# Does hadoop log any 'hdfs dfs' commands issued to the cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I would like to know if there is any record kept, in a log file somewhere, of 'hdfs dfs' commands issued to the cluster.  We need an audit capability and are wondering if some aspect of it is built-in already.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can use Ranger for Audit. HDFS Audit is quite useful as per your use case. 

However, it depends what kind of auditing you're looking for. Because Ranger is deep down tracing every activity happening in HDFS, but if you want to keep track of commands only, then there is no way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is called data governance.  There are several providers for this such as Apache Ranger, Cloudera Navigator.  Both work by ingesting the Hadoop logs to trace activity.

Comment: Thanks, so I take it that means there is no logging of the command taking place by default in our cluster now.

Comment: It depends on what log level you chose for your servers.  But you can check by running simple commands and looking at the NameNode logs.